# How to implement a component to show a number of div elements initially, and then show a number of more elements?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have build a review-system in HTML, PHP and AJAX so users can post their opinion on a website. This review-system consists of two scripts:

**PHP-script:**

```
<?php
... code
?>

<div class="overall_rating">
    <span class="num"><?=number_format($reviews_info['overall_rating'], 1)?></span>
    <span class="stars"><?=str_repeat('&#9733;', round($reviews_info['overall_rating']))?></span>
    <span class="total"><?=$reviews_info['total_reviews']?> reviews</span>
</div>
<a href="#" class="write_review_btn">Schrijf review</a>
<div class="write_review">
    <form>
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Uw voornaam" required>
        <input name="rating" type="number" min="1" max="5" placeholder="Uw beoordeling (1-5)" required>
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="Schrijf hier uw review" required></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Plaats review</button>
    </form>
</div>
<?php foreach ($reviews as $review): ?>
<div class="review">
    <h3 class="name"><?=htmlspecialchars($review['name'], ENT_QUOTES)?></h3>
    <div>
        <span class="rating"><?=str_repeat('&#9733;', $review['rating'])?></span>
        <span class="date"><?=time_elapsed_string($review['submit_date'])?></span>
    </div>
    <p class="content"><?=htmlspecialchars($review['content'], ENT_QUOTES)?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**HTML-/AJAX-script:**

```
<div class="container wow fadeInDown content home" data-wow-duration="500ms">
   <div class="reviews"></div>
   <script>
      const reviews_page_id = 1;
      fetch("reviews.php?page_id=" + reviews_page_id).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
        document.querySelector(".reviews").innerHTML = data;
        document.querySelector(".reviews .write_review_btn").onclick = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector(".reviews .write_review").style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector(".reviews .write_review input[name='name']").focus();
        };
        document.querySelector(".reviews .write_review form").onsubmit = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            fetch("reviews.php?page_id=" + reviews_page_id, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: new FormData(document.querySelector(".reviews .write_review form"))
            }).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
                document.querySelector(".reviews .write_review").innerHTML = data;
            });
        };
      });
   </script>
</div>
```

I don't know how to implement a component to show a number of div elements initially, and then show a number of more elements. For example: when opening the website only show 10 reviews initially (but keep the overall rating), and after clicking on a component show 10 more.

So it's not about filtering data, but about showing or not showing div elements. I tried to reproduce this with a simple example from Stackoverflow (see snippet below), but I still can't figure out how to implement this into my own code. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

**Example:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="reviews">
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 1</div>
         <div class="review">data 2</div>
         <div class="review">data 20</div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" title="" id="results-show-more">show more</a>
      <script>
         var limit = 5;
         var per_page = 5;
         jQuery('#reviews > div.review:gt('+(limit-1)+')').hide();
         if (jQuery('#reviews > div.review').length <= limit) {
             jQuery('#results-show-more').hide();
         }
         
         jQuery('#results-show-more').bind('click', function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             limit += per_page;
             jQuery('#reviews > div.review:lt('+(limit)+')').show();
             if (jQuery('#reviews > div.review').length <= limit) {
                 jQuery(this).hide();
             }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way of preforming a "Load More" type functionality is to display the 10 items immediately on load.

Then when the user asks for additional items, you would make an AJAX call to get the additional items, and then use Javascript to append them to the list.

---

In order to take your snippet and apply it to your code, it should be fairly straightforward. You can continue to print out all the reviews and hide the ones `.review:gt(x)` the limit. This won't follow the above pattern, but should continue to give you the results you're looking for.